# Google Maps V3 - Map OK, directions not

Tags: google-maps-api-3

This is the page:
[my site](http://mainaloski.gr/index.php?id=9)
As you can see the map is showing OK, centered and zoom as I want. The problem is that the directions are not displaying...

Google Maps code:

```
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var map;
function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.651429,22.267043);    
var myOptions = {
  zoom:9,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.722392,22.769925),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,

}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), myOptions);
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
}
function calcRoute() {
var request = {
    origin:"athens, greece", 
    destination:myLatlng,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
};
directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
  }
});
}
```

Any advive?

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two issues:

1. you have a calcRoute function to calculate and display the route, but you never call it (solution: call it, probably at the end of your initialize function).
2. the myLatLng variable is local to the initialize routine, so is not available when calcRoute tries to access it (solution: make it global).

   ```
    var directionDisplay;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    var map;
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.651429,22.267043);    

    function initialize() {
      directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
      var myOptions = {
        zoom:9,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.722392,22.769925),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      }
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map1"), myOptions);
      directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
      calcRoute();
    }

    function calcRoute() {
      var request = {
        origin:"athens, greece", 
        destination:myLatlng,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING,
      };
      directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
          directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        }
      });
    }
   ```